# Creating a shortcut .lnk using Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm having a problem with creating a shortcut using C++.

The `.lnk` file is created, but the target has a nonsense path.

Can you explain why this code is not creating a correct shortcut? Can someone could help me fix my code?

Here is the code

```
// RepChrome.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "winnls.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "objbase.h"
#include "objidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"
#include <shlobj.h>


HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj1, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc,LPCWSTR lpszarg) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLink* psl; 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj1); 
        psl->SetArguments(lpszarg);
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

            // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 

            // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
            // for success.

            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres; 
}    

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char sp[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    WCHAR p[MAX_PATH]=  { 0 };
    
    WCHAR deskPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOP, NULL, 0, deskPath);
    sprintf_s( sp,sizeof(deskPath),"%s\\My Program.lnk",deskPath);
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, NULL, 0, path);    
    
    swprintf_s( p,sizeof(path),L"%s\\My Program\\start.exe",path);

    CreateLink(p, sp, L"",L""); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: dont use `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `sprintf_s()`, `%s` expects a `char*` string, but you are giving it a `wchar*` string instead.  Also, you are passing in the wrong value for the second parameter of `sprintf_s()` and `swprintf_s()`.

You really should not be using *any* `char` data in this code at all, especially since you are just converting it to `wchar` anyway, so you should use all `wchar` strings only. Change the `lpszPathLink` parameter to `LPCWSTR`, change the `sp` buffer to `WCHAR[]`, and change `sprintf_s()` to `swprintf_s()`.

Also, since all of the values you are using for the link are `WCHAR` anyway, you should use `IShellLinkW` directly instead of the `TCHAR`-based `IShellLink`.

Also, `CreateLink()` requires `CoInitialize/Ex()` to have been called beforehand, but it is NOT being called in this code.

Try this instead:

```
// RepChrome.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "winnls.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "objbase.h"
#include "objidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"
#include <shlobj.h>

HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj1, LPCWSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc, LPCWSTR lpszarg)
{
    HRESULT hres;
    IShellLinkW* psl;

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psl));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        IPersistFile* ppf;

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description.
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj1);
        psl->SetArguments(lpszarg);
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc);

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the
        // shortcut in persistent storage.
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&ppf));
        if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
        {
            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save.
            hres = ppf->Save(lpszPathLink, TRUE);
            ppf->Release();
        }
        psl->Release();
    }
    return hres;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    WCHAR sp[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    WCHAR p[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

    WCHAR deskPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOP, NULL, 0, deskPath);
    swprintf_s( sp, _countof(sp), L"%s\\My Program.lnk", deskPath);

    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, NULL, 0, path);
    swprintf_s( p, _countof(p), L"%s\\My Program\\start.exe", path);

    CreateLink(p, sp, L"",L"");

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `IShellLink` will be mapped to `IShellLinkW` if it is `UNICODE`

Comment: @Grace *only* when `UNICODE` is defined, yes, otherwise it will map to `IShellLinkA` instead. Since `UNICODE` is not guaranteed (depends on the user's compiler setup), as since all of the data is  based on `wchar_t` specifically, `IShellLinkW` should be used directly so the code is not dependant on the compiler setup